# Set TalkBack tabbing order in toolbar

Tags: android, talkback

I have an activity with a toolbar , drawer and options menu. When i activate talk-back in acceptability mode, then i start tabbing between the views, it starts with the content of the fragment instead of the home button. how to set the home button in the toolbar to be the first, the options menu second and finally the content of the fragment when tabbing.

Comment: Define "Tabbing."  Do you mean the swipe gestures in the service, or literally using a keyboard tab button.

Comment: yes swiping gestures , as well as reading the page from top to end.